# rearranging a linear first order recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

Page 26 of *Mathematics for Economics and Finance* by M. Anthony and N. Biggs states the following equation, $y' = ay' + b$, and rearranges it as follows $(1 - a)y' = b$.

I do not understand how the authors rearrange this equation, so can anyone demonstrate this?

To add more context, the authors are concerned with finding a trivial, time-independent solution of a first-order linear recurrence. That is, they try to find a constant *y'* such that if *y*<sub>*t-1*</sub> = *y'* then the recurrence equation ensures that *y*<sub>*t*</sub> has the same value as *y'*

Comment: You don't understand how $y' = ay' + b \implies y' - ay' = b \implies y'(1 - a) = b$?

Comment: ah! i do now! thank you, Mattos

Comment: All good. Do you also understand what the authors are trying to do?

Comment: enlighten me...

Comment: You have that $$y' = \frac{b}{1-a}$$ which is time independent solution because $y'$ is a constant. Hence, if $y' = y_{t-1} = \text{constant}$, then $y' = y_{t-k}, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.